# bs-custom-file-input not working with Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I'm trying to use bs-custom-file-input in an Angular (7) app but it's not working as expected.
When a file is selected the file name is not being shown on the label as it's intended.

Where are the steps i've done to setup the module:

1. Install the bs-custom-file-input:

> npm install bs-custom-file-input --save

2. Import it to my component:

> import bsCustomFileInput from 'bs-custom-file-input';

3. Initialize the plugin:

   ngOnInit() { bsCustomFileInput.init(); }
4. HTML:

> ```
> <div class="custom-file">
>   <input id="inputGroupFile01" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
>   <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
> </div>
> ```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#file-browser) states that

> We hide the default file `<input>` via opacity and instead style the `<label>`.

This means you will have to update the `<label>`'s `innerHTML` yourself when the value of the `<input>` field changes.

[This article by *Alain Boudard*](https://medium.com/@coco.boudard/bootstrap-custom-file-input-with-angular-9039681cd025) provides code examples on how to make it work in angular.